# Solr : Query by range of name

Tags: solr

My problem is the following : 
I have a large set of user indexed in Solr. 
I would like to be able to display range of lastnames containing in each range the same number  of users, something like this :
Abar - Alac (X users between this 2 firstnames)
Alex - Amar (X users between this 2 firstnames)
Atac - Azar (X users between this 2 firstnames)

The problem is how to find the range with a solr query ?

It could be seen also as how to extract the firstname ordered alphabetically where result order modulo X = 0.

Thanks

Comment: My first thought would be to get the faceted names with their user counts and then build your ranges outside of Solr.

Comment: I agree with Rob Di Marco. There's no known to me out of the box feature of Solr, which can resolve facet ranges with equal counts. (Its more like an inverse facet feature, where you specify the count and get the ranges)

Answer (score 2):

I guess you are looking for **Alphabetic Range Bucketing**. There is no feature in Solr that provides this feature out of the box. But you can use creative hack with additional step of text analysis. This following may help in your case,

Create Field Type: letterRangeFieldType

```xml
<fieldType name="letterRangeFieldType" class="solr.TextField">
  <analyzer type="index">
    <tokenizer class="solr.PatternTokenizerFactory" pattern="^([a-zA-Z]).*" group="1" />
    <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" synonyms="letterRanges.txt" ignoreCase="true" expand="false"/>
  </analyzer>
  <analyzer type="query">
    <tokenizer class="solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory"/>
 </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

Create Field with that field type:

```xml
<field name="firstNameFacetLetter" type="letterRangeFieldType" stored="false" />
```

Create copy field that copies the first names into the new field that will bucketise:

```xml
<copyField source="firstName" dest="firstNameFacetLetter" />
```

To sum it up, while indexing the PatternTokenizerFactory takes first character from first name and maps it to the range base on the range of synonyms defined in `synonyms="letterRanges.txt"`. For example first name with `Foo` will map to `D - F`.

Finally, you can run facet on the new field with sort by `lex` order. You will get results like so,

```xml
<lst name="firstNameFacetLetter">
  <int name="A-C">99</int>
  <int name="D-F">76</int>
  <int name="G-I">52</int>
  ...
```

You need to customize to fit your ranges & requirements, but this may help you.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but I think I was not clear with the problem if have. I have a lot of user beginning with A. I want to split the result in fact. I just need to make a search of lastname beginning with A and then I would like to retrieve the first result, the Xth result, the Xth+1 result, the 2xXth result and so on... So I can get range like I describe in my question.

Answer (score 1):

Save the name as well as the representation I describe here in the index. You would have to compute it client-side before indexing, but such client-side selective duplication and denormalization of data is the stuff that give Solr wings.

Encode the first three letters of the name with 2 digits for each letter:

```
Abu -- 01 02 21
George -- 07 05 15
```

Now you have a 6-digit numerical field that you can do a 'search between'. If you want to search between `be` to `co`, simply search between `020500` to `031500`.

These numbers lend themselves perfectly to range faceting too, ie you can split the results from a to b, b to c and so on.

Some filters:

```
[a,ae] needs bucket:[010000 TO 010500]
[ae-b], 50 results from 100  needs bucket:[010500 TO 020000]&start=100&rows=50
[b-c] needs bucket:[020000 TO 030000]
[b-c], 4th result needs bucket:[020000 TO 030000]]&start=4&rows=1
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer but I think I was not clear with the problem if have. I have a lot of user beginning with A. I want to split the result in fact. I just need to make a search of lastname beginning with A and then I would like to retrieve the first result, the Xth result, the Xth+1 result, the 2xXth result and so on... So I can get range like I describe in my question.

Answer (score 1):

mailboat's answer did almost work for me, but it needed some tweak in my Solr:

Type Definition:

```
<fieldType name="vendorNameRangeFieldType" class="solr.TextField">
  <analyzer>
    <tokenizer class="solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" synonyms="vendorNameLetterRanges.txt" ignoreCase="true" expand="true"/>
 </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

Field definition:

```
<field name="vendorNameFacetLetter" type="vendorNameRangeFieldType" indexed="true" stored="true" />
```

Copying the content into the field:

```
<copyField source="Title_prop" dest="vendorNameFacetLetter" maxChars="1"/>
```

And the content of my synonym file:

```
a,b,c,d => AD
e,f,g,h => EH
i,j,k,l => IL
m,n,o,p => MP
q,r,s,t => QT
u,v,w,x,y,z => UZ
```

This creates a new field from the Title_prop field's content (using it's first char only), and then you can filter on that new field using the AD, EH, etc. groups like:

```
... &fq=vendorNameFacetLetter:QT ...
```